# How do you plot a graph when developing on a remote machine through ssh only

Tags: python, ssh

I don't have enough computing power in my desktop, so I usually develop and run the programs on a remote workstation. However, there is a frequent need to plot some graphs in order to visualize what's going on, and I can't do this directly with `Putty`. I wonder if there is some handy way of doing this.

Comment: I think what you need is probably an X server running on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `gnuplot` to plot directly within a terminal. For example:

```
gnuplot> set terminal dumb
Terminal type set to 'dumb'
Options are 'feed  size 79, 24'
gnuplot> set terminal dumb
Terminal type set to 'dumb'
Options are 'feed  size 79, 24'
gnuplot> plot(sin(x))


    1 ++---------------***---------------+---**-----------+--------**-----++
      +                *  *              +  *  **         +(sin(x)) ****** +
  0.8 ++              *   *                 *    *               *    *   ++
      |              *     *               *     *               *     *   |
  0.6 *+             *      *              *     *               *     *  ++
      |*             *      *             *       *             *       *  |
  0.4 +*            *       *             *       *             *       * ++
      |*            *        *            *        *           *        *  |
  0.2 +*           *         *            *        *           *         *++
    0 ++*          *          *          *         *          *          *++
      | *          *          *         *           *         *           *|
 -0.2 ++ *         *          *         *           *         *           *+
      |  *        *           *        *             *        *           *|
 -0.4 ++ *        *            *       *             *       *            *+
      |  *       *              *      *             *      *              *
 -0.6 ++  *      *              *      *             *      *             +*
      |    *    *               *     *               *     *              |
 -0.8 ++   *    *                *   *                 *   *              ++
      +     *  *       +         **  *   +             *  *                +
   -1 ++-----**--------+-----------**----+--------------***---------------++
     -10              -5                 0                5                10
```

Alternatively, you can use X forwarding to forward graphical things from your remote computer to your local machine.

On Windows, (which I assume you're using because you're using Putty) there's a program called XMing you could use to do this.

Some instructions for using XMing with PuTTY: http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa13/pdfs/connect-windows.pdf (see the second half of the PDF, which I've copied below)

> XMing will give you graphical support for your remote connection.
>
> (1) Download XMing from
>   http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=156984 Download
>   both Xming and Xming-fonts
>
> (2) Install both, just go with the default settings again.
>
> (3) Open Xlaunch I like the Multiple Window mode, go with whatever
>   style your heart desires Select Start no client You don’t need to
>   change anything on the next two pages.
>
> (4) Tricky step here, open PuTTY On the left settings bar, Look under
>   Connection open up more setting options for SSH Go to X11, Check
>   Enable X11 Forwarding Enter localhost:0 for X display location Enter
>   Host Name information as per the PuTTY Guide, and connect.
>
> (5) Log in, now try commands like emacs

Comment: I love the 2nd approach

Answer (score 0):

I haven't developed on Windows in a while, but I would recommend looking into installing and running from cygwin.

http://www.cygwin.com/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use putty if I'm on a fast enough connection to get away with VNC or RDP

[xrdp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xrdp/) An open source RDP server and X server capable of accepting connections from rdesktop and ms terminal server clients.

[image][image][image]